# What is the difference between presenting a ViewController vs adding a ViewController as a child

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

I just read an [interesting article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/child-view-controllers/) that introduced me to a new concept that I have never heard before, which is adding a `ViewController` as a child of another `ViewController`. The article uses the `UIActivityIndicatorView` as an example to demonstrate a common use for when to use the `addChild` method and this got me wondering why would you use that method instead of just presenting the view controller.

The part I don't fully understand is the benefit of using that specific method since both presenting and adding as a child could be modular in a way that they can be reusable.

When would you use `addChild` instead of just presenting it? When does that make sense?

### addChild:

```
let parent = UIViewController()
let child = MyViewController()

parent.view.addSubview(child.view)
parent.addChild(child)
child.didMove(toParent: parent)
```

### Present:

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle:nil)
let myVC  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewController") as! MyViewController
self.present(myVC , animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that when you present a controller, it becomes modal, and when you add it as a child controller, it doesn't. The difference is in semantics and use cases.

### Modal

As an example of modal window, imagine a window with an OK button in macOS that prevents you from interacting with the parent window until you close it.

Hence why there can be only one view controller presented by a particular controller: the presented controller becomes “main” for user interaction, and the user must close it to return to the parent window.

A typical example of a modal window is an alert.

### Child

But a child view controller is a different story. There can be any amount of them on a particular VC.

The parent controller becomes sort of container for child view controllers. For example, there can be a dashboard with multiple panels, and each panel can be a separate controller. This allows to separate logic between different pieces of an application instead of cramming everything into a single controller, to implement user customization in easy way, etc.

A typical example of a parent-child controller interaction is `UINavigationController`: the navigation controller is the parent, and all view controllers pushed into it are its children. We don't make an uber controller with the whole application's logic, we separate it between different screens, and the navigation controller is only responsible for presentation.

Comment: @ efpies - So, is it common to have multiple/many view controllers within one view controller acting like independent views (kind of) to construct the UI? I have been subclassing and presenting views independently but it looks like I'm missing some good stuff, particularly the fact that you keep the logic within the child view controller and you don't end up with massive parent view controllers.

Comment: @fs_tigre From my experience, it's not really THAT common to split controllers like that (meaning you probably won't do it in each app), but it has certain applications. For example, one time we developed an iPad app with tabs on the left that switched different forms in the middle. The container was only dealing with navigation, and the form controller was dealing with a form. Each row of a form was a separate controller as well incorporating different logic based on a row type (text, number, drawing). That allowed to make dynamic forms defined in a JSON template as customer wanted.

Comment: @fs_tigre So the reason for splitting controllers like that is to make them work like “building blocks”. By doing like that, you make sure that every controller does what exactly it has to do (and that drastically reduces complications comparing to a single controller approach), but at the same time not overengineer. Like if there're custom tabs in your app switching screens, in case those screens have different logic (like forms), I'd make a separate tabs controller and separate controllers for screens. But if your tabs only switch pictures, I'd have a single controller with tabs and pictures

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. [`addChild`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchild) is when you want to *embed* the view controller in you parent view controller (you will also need to follow up with a `view.addSubview(child.view)`). [`present`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) is when you want to, well, present it... think of it as a change of screens.

`addChild`:

[image]

`present`:

[image]

Comment: My confusion still is with the fact that you could make the background transparent and present it in `.fullScreen` adjust your content to whatever you want then you end up with almost the same thing.

Comment: True. But the system provides `present` to make things simpler... you get animations for free, and it also adapts based on the device size and orientation.